# What am I doing wrong with this Rest api and nginx front end reverse proxy?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am trying to get the front end and backend working together for the spring boot pet clinic app. I have already done ng --prod on a windows pc and then used github to transfer my code to a VM. I had it working once but only on IE but it doesn't again I don't know what's wrong. Please help it's done my head in for a few weeks.

**nginx.conf file:**

```
worker_processes 1;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    sendfile off;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    #access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    #error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";


    server {
        #listen 8443 ssl;
        listen 4200;
        #server_name  localhost;

        #ssl_certificate      localhost.crt;
        #ssl_certificate_key  localhost.key;

        location / {
            root        /AngularApp/dist;
            index   index.html;

         }      
          location /api/ {
                proxy_pass_header Server;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
                proxy_connect_timeout 20;
                proxy_read_timeout 20;
                proxy_pass http://springcommunity:9966/petclinic;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

}
}
```

**Dockefile for front end.**

```
FROM nginx
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN rm /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY /nginx.conf        /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY /AngularApp /AngularApp
WORKDIR /AngularApp
```

**docker-compose file:**

version: '3.7'

```
services:

  springcommunity:
    image: springcommunity/spring-petclinic-rest
    ports:
     - "9966:9966" 

  web:
    container_name: nginx
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"

    depends_on:      
      - springcommunity
    links:
      - springcommunity
    restart: always
```

**environment.prod.ts and environment.ts file before ng --prod (production)**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  REST_API_URL:'http://localhost:9966/petclinic/'
};
```

**Things I have tried and failed:**

export const environment = {
  production: true,
  REST_API_URL:'http://springcommunity:9966/petclinic'
};

Exposing 4200 in the Dockerfile for the front end.

I have tried port mapping in docker compose:
example:
4200:9966

9966:4200

Exposing 9966 as well in the compose file.

The front end and backend work but just not together, only individually I have a feeling that one container needs to be delayed the front end I have done some google searching but can't find a viable option. I have no idea how to do it, please help.

**Update  5/06/2020**
I am currently running a wait-for.sh so the backend runs before the the web container but now nginx exits with a error code 0. I am also trying to see the nginx error logs but I can't get to this could someone please shed some light on this?

Comment: Add `EXPOSE 4200` to your dockerfile?

Comment: tried that but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

If your frontend can't reach the backend on that VM may be that your docker containers are not o the same network.
You can try REST_API_URL:'http://0.0.0.0:9966/petclinic'

Or can specify a custom networks in docker-compose file and use REST_API_URL:'http://springcommunity:9966/petclinic'

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks